# Rules for determining the order of keyboard events? (Python)

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I currently have a situation like this:

```py
keyboard.on_press(Function1)
keyboard.on_press_key(';', Function2)
keyboard.on_press_key('/', Function3)
```

Through trial I've found that the on_press_key() events always happen first (and the logic of my program is dependent on it) but I have no idea why, or if it's a hardware- or OS- specific thing that could be inconsistent and break if used on other systems (?).

I've tried searching but couldn't find anything on this. Is there a reliable way to know the order in which the events are triggered, or force them to be triggered in a particular order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the flow of control is as follows:

- [keyboard.on_press](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/__init__.py#L470) adds an entry in the `handlers` object stored in the global `_listener` obj.
- [keyboard.on_press_key](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/__init__.py#L506) adds an entry in the `nonblocking_keys` dict.

When a key event is raised, `process` is called, which **calls pre_process_event (itself calling all callbacks in the `nonblocking_keys` dict) BEFORE calling the handlers**.

```py
    def process(self):
        """
        Loops over the underlying queue of events and processes them in order.
        """
        assert self.queue is not None
        while True:
            event = self.queue.get()
            if self.pre_process_event(event):
                self.invoke_handlers(event)
            self.queue.task_done()
```

However this is just an implementation detail which might evolve with new versions, you'd better not rely on it. Could you for ex call `Function1` in `Function2` and `Function3` ?